# When does an asynchronous routine change to a synchronous one?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

From what I know , an asynchronous send (MPI_Isend) changes to a synchronous one (MPI_Send) when the buffer is full , so it must wait until appropriate space is available , so I wanted to know whether an asynchronous receive (MPI_Irecv) changes to a synchronous one (MPI_recv) when the buffer is empty ?

Comment: `MPI_Isend()` is a non blocking (aka immediate) send. `MPI_Send()` is a blocking send. `MPI_SSend()` is a blocking synchronous send and `MPI_Issend()` is a non blocking synchronous send. I do not know what you mean by synchronous/asynchronous, but this is likely not what it means for MPI.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I am sorry , I missused the two terms , I meant blocking when I used synchronous and nonblocking when I used asynchronous.

Comment: By definition, `MPI_Isend()` and `MPI_Irecv()` return immediately. If you witness `MPI_Isend()` not returning immediately, this is either a bug in the MPI library you are using, or a limitation (for example if you previously sent an insane number of yet unmatched `MPI_Isend()`, or your process cannot allocate any more memory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know `MPI_Isend` will not turn into a blocking routine because of buffers filling up. The reason is that `Isend` uses the user's send buffer, so there is no problem with internal buffering.

Maybe you should clarify what you mean by "the buffer". The user send buffer, or something internal? The user buffer is never "full" or "empty": the only thing you can say is that before `MPI_Wait` the buffer should not be reused, and after the wait it can safely be.

Comment: But what if the user buffer is shared with multiple instances of Isend() in the same process rank?

Comment: Each `Isend` gives you a request, you'd have to wait for all those.